# @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) to treat inner and outer classes differently. Is @JsonInclude transitive?

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

I have an outer class for which JsonIncude strategy is defined as follows:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RestSelectionContext {
    public RestPayrollDetails payrollDetails;
    public RestFamilyDetails familyDetails;
    ...
    public boolean isAdmin;
}
```

then I have the enclosed PayrollDetails class on which I want to implement the opposite @JsonInclude strategy, ie so that is show null values:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class RestPayrollDetails {
    public BigDecimal taxRate;
    public BigDecimal niRate;
    public Money employeeNetSalary;
}
```

Is that going to work? And, a bigger question, is @JsonInclude property transitive - meaning, does it apply to all the enclosed classes, or only to the class it has been declared in?

I fully expect the answers like "Try and see if that worked". That's not what I'm asking, the question is more "Is that a valid way of using @JsonInclude" and what is the expected behavior, irrespective of he library version?